# Why fosmessager "destroys" the entity user of fosuser

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, fosuserbundle, message-bundle

I followed the [doc](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSMessageBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/01-installation.md) to integrate fosmessagerbundle, at the end of step 5 I ran the command

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

I got this message

```
DROP INDEX UNIQ_957A647992FC23A8 ON fos_user;
DROP INDEX UNIQ_957A6479A0D96FBF ON fos_user;
ALTER TABLE fos_user DROP username, DROP username_canonical, DROP email, DROP em
ail_canonical, DROP enabled, DROP salt, DROP password, DROP last_login, DROP loc
ked, DROP expired, DROP expires_at, DROP confirmation_token, DROP password_reque
sted_at, DROP roles, DROP credentials_expired, DROP credentials_expire_at;
```

i have properly followed the instructions, but the user entity will be empty.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I deleted the 4 entities and the modification on user entities.
I re-created a bundle message,
I created in Messge the 4 entities

Comment: I got this error message
`Found 15 mapped entities:
[OK]   BO\{...}
[FAIL] BO\MessageBundle\Entity\Message
The target-entity MessageBundle\Entity\Thread cannot be found in 'BO\MessageBund
le\Entity\Message#thread'.`